# Make application available across all shells

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have developed a java application that i want to publish to my users.
This application is an ancillary application used by many different shell scripts, such as sh, su, bash and zsh to name a few. My current approach is to put my program in /opt/myapp with a sh script to run the app.

```
#!/bin/bash 
"$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" -jar /opt/myapp/myapp-1.0.jar $@
```

And I ask my users to add `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/myapp` to their source such as `~/.zsrch`. However I keep having issues with some scripts or programs not finding the app `bash: myapp: command not found` however it would work fine in /bin/su and /bin/zhc.

What is the right way to "install" my app on Linux and MacOS so that it is available across all shells.

The /opt/myapp folder

```
bash-3.2$ ls -l
total 40624
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel        66 Apr  2 05:06 myapp
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  20794374 Apr  2 05:05 myapp-1.0.jar
```

Path

```
bash-3.2$ echo $PATH
/opt/myapp:/Library/TeX/texbin::/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:::/Users/accoun/bin
```

One of the examples is that an IntelliJ plugin runs the app to get information.
The plugin will run `/bin/bash -c myapp version` as a process, however the output of that process is that `bash: myapp: command not found`. However if i open a console the run bash it worked just fine.

```
~ » /bin/bash                                    accoun@MACC02YX270LVDQ

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
bash-3.2$ echo $PATH
/opt/myapp:/Library/TeX/texbin::/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:::/Users/accoun/bin
bash-3.2$ myapp version
Myapp version 1.0
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: "I keep having issues" - what issues? Please [edit] and be explicit.

Comment: Are you a bot? It litterly says that "However I keep having issues with some scripts or programs not finding the app."

Comment: So what are the error messages?

Comment: Not finding the app 'command not found', how is that not clear?

Comment: Have you checked to see if they have Java installed (correctly)?

Comment: It does not even get to the Java app. The shell script I have in the /opt/mymapp/myapp is the one not found.

Comment: Have you asked them to run `rehash`?

Comment: Tried that, but it did not work

Comment: This question has a very simple answer: Depending on where `$PATH` is changed/extended, the change may affect only Bash and/or only interactive shells. Put a symlink in `/usr/local/bin` and make sure that's in `$PATH` for all users.

Answer (score 0):

As @DanielB mentioned in the comments mentioned, both the problem and the solution are very simple. You have added your program/script/app to the wrong directory. You should add it to `/usr/local/bin/` as that complies with the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) (and all defaults on the Linux system [on most distros] comply with the FHS). The said directory is by default in the `$PATH` variable of bash, so it will be accessible for all scripts and applications.

Scripts and applications **do not** use your `.bashrc` or your `$PATH` variable. Most of those will use the `$PATH` variable that is set in `/etc/profile`. Reason for this being is that scripts and applications run in a non-interactive shell. You can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43659084/source-bashrc-in-a-script-not-working#:%7E:text=bashrc%20from%20a%20script%20will,non%2Dinteractive%20shells%20by%20default.&text=Or%3A%20Try%20to%20to%20emulate,bashrc%20.) SO answer.

So you have two options at first glance:

1. Add the application to `/usr/local/bin/` - better practice.
2. Leave it in `/opt/` and add that path to the `$PATH` variable in `/etc/profile`.